# How to use Assertion in SeeTest

Tags: java, junit5, seetest, experitest

I'm currently trying to automate the testing of an Android application using SeeTest Automation.

But I don't know how to use assertions.

Do I need to export SeeTest code once and add assertions in editing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that Seetest itself doesn't have the ability to implement assertions.

Copy the code, edit it in eclipse and write the assertion.
After that, it worked by running it with JUnit.